# Extract number from str with pattern

Tags: string, python-3.x

Example like `"3-5/description"`. I'd like extract the numbers next to the dash `-`, which are `3` and `5` in this example. The `description` next to the `/` is a str containing no number.

I want a tool to help me extract number from str like this like this `func("3-5/description")`returns `[3,5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a regex match to capture the digits before and after the '-'

```
import re

def func(input):
    return re.match(r'(\d+)[-](\d+)', x).groups()

func("3-5/description")
```